# pandas: how to sort a grouped dataframe by mean amount?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Speciality     Amount
Greek          15
Greek          16 
Italian        8
Italian        11
Italian        13
```

I have now aggregated the mean and count for each speciality:

```
df_by_spec_count = df.groupby('Speciality').agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

Now I want to print the top 10 specialities with the highest mean.

I've tried this:

```
print df_by_spec_count.sort_values(by='count',ascending=False).head()
```

But I get a KeyError. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is remove top level by [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df_by_spec_count = df.groupby('Speciality').agg(['mean', 'count'])
df_by_spec_count.columns = df_by_spec_count.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df_by_spec_count)

                 mean  count
Speciality                  
Greek       15.500000      2
Italian     10.666667      3

print (df_by_spec_count.sort_values(by='count',ascending=False).head())
                 mean  count
Speciality                  
Italian     10.666667      3
Greek       15.500000      2
```

But better solution is specify column `Amount` for aggregating in `groupby` - get **no** `Multiindex` in columns:

```
df_by_spec_count = df.groupby('Speciality')['Amount'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
print (df_by_spec_count)
                 mean  count
Speciality                  
Greek       15.500000      2
Italian     10.666667      3

print (df_by_spec_count.sort_values(by='count',ascending=False).head())
                 mean  count
Speciality                  
Italian     10.666667      3
Greek       15.500000      2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have hierarchical columns so you need to pass a tuple to select the appropriate column level to sort on:

```
In [324]:

df_by_spec_count.sort_values(by=('Amount','count'),ascending=False).head()
Out[324]:
               Amount      
                 mean count
Speciality                 
Italian     10.666667     3
Greek       15.500000     2
```

You can see why if you look at the original grouped result:

```
In[321]:
df_by_spec_count

Out[321]:
               Amount      
                 mean count
Speciality                 
Greek       15.500000     2
Italian     10.666667     3

In [325]:
df_by_spec_count.columns

Out[325]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['Amount'], ['mean', 'count']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```